# Java - JInternalFrame - Unable to close JInternalFrame from a JFrame‏

Tags: java, swing, terminate, jinternalframe

I'm looking to close a JInternalFrame from a JFrame using a button on the JFrame.

From the code below you will notice that I've attempted using the setVisible(), hide() or dispose() methods but these didn't work.

```
    //
public void dismisssetupReceiverJIframe() {
    System.out.println("\n dismisssetupReceiverJIframe() - START OF dismisssetupReceiverJIframe() ");

    // Check if the the setup receiver open flag is true, if so then execute subsequent steps. If not do nothing.
    //if (isSetupRecvScnOpen == true) {

        // Dispose of the setupReceiverJIframe
        setupReceiverJIframe setupReceiverJIframe = new setupReceiverJIframe();
        setupReceiverJIframe.setVisible(false);
        //setupReceiverJIframe.hide();
        setupReceiverJIframe.dispose();

        // The text areas, label and button are in the JFrame           
        btnOneTextArea.setVisible(true); 
        btnTwoTextArea.setVisible(true); 
        btnThreeTextArea.setVisible(true); 
        btnFourTextArea.setVisible(true);
        btnFiveTextArea.setVisible(true);  
        btnSixTextArea.setVisible(true);  
        btnSevenTextArea.setVisible(true);  
        btnEightTextArea.setVisible(true);
        btnNineTextArea.setVisible(true);
        btnTenTextArea.setVisible(true); 
        btnElevenTextArea.setVisible(true); 
        btnTwelveTextArea.setVisible(true);
        btnThirteenTextArea.setVisible(true); 
        btnFourteenTextArea.setVisible(true); 
        btnFifteenTextArea.setVisible(true); 
        btnSixteenTextArea.setVisible(true); 
        btnSeventeenTextArea.setVisible(true);
        notifMssgLabel.setVisible(true);

        btnSaveAll.setVisible(true);
    //}

    System.out.println("\n dismisssetupReceiverJIframe() - END OF dismisssetupReceiverJIframe() ");

}
```

Is there another method or way to close the JInternalFrame from a JFrame?

Thanks for your assistance

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [`JInterFrame#setClosed`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JInternalFrame.html#setClosed%28boolean%29)

> Closes this internal frame if the argument is true.

```
setupReceiverJIframe.setClosed(true);
```